# How to convert a weighted, directed graph into a discrete Markov transition matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request, markov-chains

Suppose that I have matrix `matT1` at time t and `matT2` at time t+1:

```
matT1 = {
         {0.98, 0.95, 1.00, 0.85, 1.40}, 
         {1.46, 0.36, 0.96, 0.15, 0.97}, 
         {0.24, 1.20, 1.40, 0.96, 0.46}, 
         {1.10, 1.30, 0.03, 0.81, 0.53}, 
         {1.30, 1.50, 1.30, 0.51, 0.42}
       };

matT2 = {
         {0.44, 1.00, 0.77, 1.20, 0.61}, 
         {0.58, 0.57, 0.65, 0.19, 1.00}, 
         {1.40, 0.14, 1.20, 1.40, 0.96}, 
         {1.40, 0.95, 0.74, 0.56, 0.47}, 
         {0.98, 0.45, 1.30, 0.34, 0.25}
       };
```

Note that these matrices represent two different weighted directed graphs with 5 vertices. Elements of these two matrices are assigned to one of the five states `s1=[0, 0.5]`, `s2=(0.5, 1]`, `s3=(1, 1.5]` etc.

```
r1T1=BoolEval[0<= matT1<=0.5]/.{1->s1};
r2T1=BoolEval[0.5<matT1<= 1]/.{1-> s2};
r3T1=BoolEval[1<matT1<=1.5]/.{1 -> s3};
r4T1=BoolEval[1.5<matT1<=2]/.{1 -> s4};
r5T1=BoolEval[2<matT1<=2.5]/.{1 -> s5};
matT1S = r1T1 + r2T1 + r3T1 + r4T1 + r5T1 // MatrixForm

r1T2=BoolEval[0<=matT2<=0.5]/.{1 -> s1};
r2T2=BoolEval[0.5<matT2<=1]/.{1 -> s2};
r3T2=BoolEval[1<matT2<=1.5]/.{1 -> s3};
r4T2=BoolEval[1.5<matT2<=2]/.{1 -> s4};
r5T2=BoolEval[2<matT2<=2.5]/.{1 -> s5};
matT2S = r1T2 + r2T2 + r3T2 + r4T2 + r5T2 // MatrixForm
```

respectively yield:

```
matT1S = {
          {s2, s2, s2, s2, s3},
          {s3, s1, s2, s1, s2},
          {s1, s3, s3, s2, s1},
          {s3, s3, s1, s2, s2},
          {s3, s3, s3, s2, s1}
         };
matT2S = {
          {s1, s2, s2, s3, s2},
          {s2, s2, s2, s1, s2},
          {s3, s1, s3, s3, s2},
          {s3, s2, s2, s2, s1},
          {s2, s1, s3, s1, s1}
         };
```

We then derive a map of transition from `matT1S` to `matT2S`by manually comparing the states in both matrices.

```
Clear[n, states, map];
n = Length[matT2S];
states = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5};
map = {};

Do[
   If[matT1S[[i, j]] == states[[1]] &&  
      matT2S[[i, j]] == states[[2]], 
      AppendTo[map, {i, j}]
     ], {i, n}, {j, n}
  ]  
 
Length[map]   (* gives 0 *)
```

For each pair of `states`, I run the above code to obtain the following map:

[image]

Rows are associated with time t and columns  with t+1. This map illustrates that, out of 3 links in state `s1` at time t, 1 remains in `s1` at t+1, and 1 moves to `s3` at t+1 and 1 moves to `s5` at t+1. Other numbers in the map should be read likewise. Using this map,

```
traMap={
         {1,0,1,0,1},
         {1,0,1,1,0},
         {0,2,0,0,0}, 
         {1,1,2,4,2},
         {0,1,2,3,1}
       };
transMatrix=
  DiagonalMatrix[1/Total[traMap,
  {2}]].traMap
```

A row-stochastic transition matrix as:

```
transMatrix = {
    {1/3,   0,    1/3,   0,   1/3},
    {1/3,   0,    1/3,  1/3,   0 },
    {0,     1,     0,    0,    0 },
    {1/10, 1/10,  1/5,  2/5,  1/5},
    {0,    1/7,   2/7,  3/7,  1/7}
  };
```

and

```
MatrixPower[transMatrix, 100]
```

produces the following limiting distribution:

[image]

This limiting distribution translates the current vector `(3, 3, 2, 10, 7)` to `(0.17, 0.26, 0.22, 0.23, 0.12)*(3, 3, 2, 10, 7)`.

My question: Although I found out the transition, I do not know which linkages are in each state in the final period t+100. I like to know the specific linkages associated the new distribution `(0.17, 0.26, 0.22, 0.23, 0.12)*(3, 3, 2, 10, 7)`.

Would it be possible to write a function `transMatrix[matrixT_,matrixT1_]:=...` to produce: a transition matrix (row stochastic matrix), a final distribution of the linkages across three states, and subsets of the linkages across each state?

Comment: Can you give an example of a few "linkages", say, of length three ( $t+3$ .)

Comment: @Anton Antonov: I have only two time periods and 3 states in the example. Therefore, there is no length-3 linkage. Max linkage has length-2. From `s1` to `s2`, the set of binary links with vertex names is  {{2,2},{4,3},{3,5}} because I have a total of 5 vertices; from `s2` to `s3`, the set of links is {{3,4},{1,4}}; and from `s3` to `s1`, the set is {{3,2},{5,2}}. To find the binary links associated with the limiting distribution, we need to identify the specific binary links that is likely to end up with the state implied by the limiting distribution. I hope I am not confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more streamlined way to produce the matrices in OP (not an answer):

```
ClearAll[toStates]
toStates[t_, s_, m_] := Map[s[[Total[1 - UnitStep[t - #]]]] &, m, {2}]

thresholds = {0, .5, 1., 1.5};
states = {s1, s2, s3};

m1S = toStates[thresholds, states, matT1];
m2S = toStates[thresholds, states, matT2];

{m1S, m2S} == {matT1S, matT2S}
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
maP[m1_, m2_, st_] := PadRight[KeySort[GroupBy[
      Join @@ (Transpose /@ Transpose[{m1, m2}]), 
      First -> Last, KeySort[Counts[#]] /@ st /. _Missing -> 0 &]] /@ 
    st /. _Missing -> {0}]

maP[m1S, m2S, states]

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ %
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  2 & 3 & 1 \\
>  3 & 5 & 2 \\
>  2 & 4 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
tm = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ map;
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ tm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} \\
>  \frac{3}{10} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{5} \\
>  \frac{2}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{1}{3} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thank you for a nice function. It works as expected if all the elements in `map` are positive, but it does not work if there is a zero transition from, say, s1 to s2. I will edit my question with a new pair of matrices and the intervals. You may try your Code with the example.

Comment: @Tugrul, the new version of `map` should work for cases with zero transitions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also edited the question with a new matrix. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Your `map` function has a problem. It always gives me 3 by 3 matrix in the original example matrix I gave, although I run the code with a 5 by 5 matrix as in the edited question. It looks like the `map` code does not accept the new matrices `m1S` and `m2S`.

Comment: @Tugrul, hope the new version works in general.

Comment: Now it works as expected. One tiny revision is needed to make sure that the thresholds (intervals) are in the form of [0, 0.5], (0.5, 1.0], (1.0, 1.5], etc. I like to make sure that upper values in intervals are closed (inclusive), while lower values (except zero in s1) are open (exclusive). Currently, I do not know the convention you implement.

Comment: I think the Code still has a problem. I give a 5 by 5 matrix in the question above, but the outcome of `maP[...]` is a totally different matrix. I noticed that still the very very early example 3 by 3 matrix is reproduced by `maP[...]`.

Comment: I am very sorry. Your Code works. I confused you due to my inattention to the intervals. Now I tried it again and got the correct result. This part of the job is done. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the question. It seems to me that you can make the transition matrix by making the graph adjacency matrix row stochastic.

Here is an example with question’s `matT1`:

```
matT1rs = DiagonalMatrix[1/Total[matT1, {2}]].matT1;

Total[matT1rs, {2}]

(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)

MarkovProcessProperties[DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, matT1rs]]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that I could not explain the problem well. I will edit the question to be more precise. Thanks.